# Delete fields from a firestore document using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to delete fields from a Firestore document with no success.

I've searched for the error messages that I get but the few pages I can find link to stuff that I'm already doing. I'm sure this something simple but I'm at a loss at the moment.

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;

const firestore = new Firestore({
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
});
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);


var updateDoc = firestore.collection('XXXXXXXX').doc('XXXXXXX').update({
    fieldToBeDeleted: FieldValue.delete()
});
```

I expect the field to be deleted but instead I get this error message:

```
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Document. Couldn't serialize object of type "DeleteTransform". Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the 'new' operator).
    at WriteBatch.update (XXXXXXXXXX\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\write-batch.js:359:23)
    at DocumentReference.update (XXXXXXXXXX\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:387:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (XXXXXXXXXX)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing use of the Firebase Admin SDK and the Cloud SDK.  Try using symbols from just one or the other, and not both at the same time.  You're using `Firestore` from the Cloud SDK, but `FieldValue.delete()` from the admin SDK.

Comment: That did it Doug.  Thanks for the help.
I removed the 2 lines of admin SDK stuff from the top, and changed the delete line to "fieldToBeDeleted: Firestore.FieldValue.delete()"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you cannot mix symbols between the Cloud SDK and the Firebase Admin SDK (which wraps the Cloud SDK).  Firebase exports its own symbols, which cannot be used with calls that go directly to the Cloud SDK.  Callers are obliged to use one or the other, but not both at the same time.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code that ended up working, using just the Cloud SDK, without the Firebase Admin SDK.

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

const firestore = new Firestore({
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
});
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);


var updateDoc = firestore.collection('XXXXXXXX').doc('XXXXXXX').update({
    fieldToBeDeleted: Firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Cloud Functions with a write batch. Initially, I was allowed to use docRef = admin.firestore().collection('XXXXXXX').doc('XXXXXX') along with FieldValue.delete() from the Cloud SDK.

It wasn't until just recently that I started getting an error in my code, and I did not know what my problem was (as I did not change this part of the code) until I came across this question and Doug's answer. Anyway, I approached the solution a little differently (yet still in line with Doug's recommendation) and went solely with the Admin SDK.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const firestoreInstance = admin.firestore();
const fieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
const docRef = firestoreInstance.collection('XXXXXXX').doc('XXXXXXX');
const batch = firestoreInstance.batch();

...

batch.update(docRef, { fieldToBeDeleted: fieldValue.delete() });

return batch.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had today a similar error and it turned out to be a version mismatch issue.
My app had a library that was importing `firebase-admin`, but an older version of it. The `FieldValue.delete` was imported from the newer version and saved by a code that was importing the older version of `firebase-admin`. This is why the symbol was not recognised.